# Woocomerce вариативный товар

Tags: woocommerce

Есть вариативный товар кровать. Для каждого размера кровати есть своя цена, но кровать может быть с ящиками, или без них. Как сделать так чтобы для выбранного размера кровати можно было добавить цену ящиков если это необходимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого делается несколько вариаций
- сначала выбор "С ящиками" или "Без ящиков"
- потом выбор размера "160x190", "160x200", "160x210"

Ну или же наоборот, сначала выбор размера, потом с ящиками или без ящиков, это уже как вашей душе угодно

Атрибуты
https://prnt.sc/mj4wxd

Вариации
https://prnt.sc/mj4x1y

Вариация товара
https://prnt.sc/mj4xco